# JQuery .get function vars

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once again having problems being a new to javascript. I want to get the reply from my PHP script using JQuery's get. Here's my function

```
function getNext(){
    var returnData = null;
    $.get("get.php", {task:'next'}, function(responseText){
        returnData = responseText; }, "text");  
    return returnData;      
}
```

Now obviously the function returns null even though the request was successful. Why?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because ajax is asynchronous, it acts independently on its own and so by the time the `return` statement completes, it hasn't been assigned yet.

Answer (score 5):

```
function getNext(){
   var returnData;  
   $.ajax({
      url: "get.php",
      data: {task:'next'},
      success: function(responseText) { returnData = responseText },
      async: false;
   });
   return returnData;      
}
```

Note that this may "freeze" the UI because Javascript is single threaded -- it will wait until it receives the response from the server.

You may want to refactor it so that the action is called in the `success` callback. Could you show us what triggers the invokation of the `getNext` method?

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. I understand(ish) now.The code is invoked by document ready, but I'm not coding anything to be used merely discovering AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getNext(){
  var returnData = null;
  $.get("get.php", {task:'next'}, 
    function(responseText){
      returnData = responseText;
      alert('Data ' + responseText);
    });
}
```

You will have to poll whether `returnData` contains actual data that you want periodically (or put your code into the callback method)